# R - cartography package - position of legend?

Tags: r, cartography, legend

I'm using the `cartography` package in R to plot a choropleth map. However, I have a problem placing the legend, which can be placed by means of the `legend.pos` argument, but which always overlaps with my map. The documentation says:

> legend.pos    : position of the legend, one of "topleft", "top",
>   "topright", "right", "bottomright", "bottom", "bottomleft", "left" or
>   a vector of two coordinates in map units (c(x, y)). If legend.pos is
>   "n" then the legend is not plotted.

(Source: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cartography/cartography.pdf)

Using "right", "bottomright" etc, the legend still overlaps my map; thus, I'd like to use the coordinates version. However, I tried already lots of different combinations, but the legend does not appear in the map anymore.

**My question is: How to understand "coordinates in map units"? How can I find the right coordinates to that the legend becomes visible?**

Here is my code; as you can see, I use the standard "nuts0" map.

```
choroLayer(spdf = nuts0.spdf, df = nuts0.df, var = "cdp", 
           breaks=seq(from=0, to=240, by=40),
           col = farb, 
           colNA="grey70",
           border = "grey40", lwd = 0.5, 
           legend.pos = "bottomright",
           legend.title.txt = "No. companies",
           add = F)
```

Comment: The 'map units' will be determined by the projection system you're in. They will either be degrees:minutes:seconds or meters. I think in R you can use `proj4string(spdf)` to get your crs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer from RoperMaps:  Get the map units by means of `proj4string(nuts0.spdf)`